# To group by department take sum(sales) and the create separate column with sum(sales) for the entire table in hive?

Tags: hive

I have a table like this

```
Department     Sales
A               2000
A               2000
A               3000
B               1000
B               4000
B               2000
C               2500
C               2000
C               2000
```

No I want My output like

```
Department          Sales   Total_Sales
A                    7000     20500
B                    7000     20500
C                    6500     20500
```

How to achieve this using hive, Window functions?

Comment: Did you read the documentation: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics?

Answer (score 0):

It can be something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       Department,
       SUM(Sales) OVER (PARTITION BY Department) Sales,
       SUM(Sales) OVER () Total_Sales
FROM source_table
```

But

```
SELECT Department,
       SUM(Sales) Sales,
FROM source_table
GROUP BY Department WITH ROLLUP
```

may be more useful (total sales will be calculated in additional row with `Department IS NULL`).

Answer (score 0):

```
select *,sum(sales) over() as Total_Sales 
from(select department,sum(sales) as sales from orders group by department)t1;
```